# Python HTML code syntax error

Tags: python, html

I am getting the following syntax error when trying to add a hyperlink,I looked at the HTML code for href,HTML code seems right but python is throwing a syntax error..can anyone help?

Python code

```
    msg_body=("<HTML><head></head>"
          "<body>Test"
          "<br>Hi All, <br>"
          "<b>Wiki @<a href="%s">%s</a> (listed @ go\link) <br><br>"
          "<b>Release notes:</b> %s  <br><br>" 
          "<b>Host/Riva Build Combo:</b><br>%s<br><br>" 
          "<b>Loading instructions:</b><br>%s<br><br>"
          "<b>CR fixes:</b><br>%s<br><br>"
          "Thanks,<br>"
          "B team"
          "</body></html>"
          ) % (wikiURL,Releasenotes,table,Load_ins,crInfo)
```

Error:-

```
    "<b>Wiki @<a href="%s">%s</a> (listed @ go\wbit) <br><br>"                                                      ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Would you not need to concatenate the strings together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
msg_body="""<HTML><head></head>
          <body>Test
          <br>Hi All, <br>
          <b>Wiki @<a href="%s">%s</a> (listed @ go\link) <br><br>
          <b>Release notes:</b> %s  <br><br>
          <b>Host/Riva Build Combo:</b><br>%s<br><br>
          <b>Loading instructions:</b><br>%s<br><br>
          <b>CR fixes:</b><br>%s<br><br>
          Thanks,<br>
          B team
          </body></html>
          """ % (wikiURL, Releasenotes, table, Load_ins, crInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong line is

```
"<b>Wiki @<a href="%s">%s</a> (listed @ go\link) <br><br>"
```

You need to escape the quotes inside quotes like that:

```
"<b>Wiki @<a href=\"%s\">%s</a> (listed @ go\link) <br><br>"
```

like that:

```
'<b>Wiki @<a href="%s">%s</a> (listed @ go\link) <br><br>'
```

or (as suggested by @ragsagar) like that:

```
"""
<b>Wiki @<a href="%s">%s</a> (listed @ go\link) <br><br>
"""
```